# What's the practical way to keep ChannelId in netty 5.0?

Tags: java, sockets, netty, serversocket, socketchannel

I'm implementing a socket server with netty 5.0 for client connection.
I need to keep socket connection with each callee at all time and send message to inform the callee identically.
Currently I have a self-defined class called "*ChannelMapper*" which stores the "MAC address" and "ChannelId (as String)" as a relation record in DB.
(Since the caller only send "MAC address" of callee as identification to server for connection)

```
public ChannelMapper(String chid, String macAddr) {
    this.chid = chid;
    this.macAddr = macAddr;
}
```

Each time when the callee is connected to server, it sends its own MAC address and then server would store a self-defined "*ChannelMapper*" record for identification. I have a "*ChannelGroup*" for keeping all connected socket channels.
And I also have another Map to keep the real "*ChannelId*" object since netty doesn't have an API to create "*ChannelId*" object by the String form of "*ChannelId*" (says *channelId.asLongText()*)

```
public static ChannelGroup channels = new DefaultChannelGroup(GlobalEventExecutor.INSTANCE);
public static Map<String, ChannelId> mapChannels = new HashMap<>();
```

Each time a client is connected, it would run method "*channelActive*" and store the channel info in DB and Map separately for future usage.

```
@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    Channel channel = ctx.channel();
    ChannelId channelId = channel.id();
    String chid = channelId.asLongText();
    channels.add(channel);
    mapChannels.put(chid, channelId);
}
```

So if server would like to send message to client through socket, I need to query DB to get corresponding "*ChannelId*" in String form. And then get actual "*ChannelId*" object stored in Map because the only way to get "*ChannelId*" is calling the API "*Channel find(ChannelId id)*" in "*ChannelGroup*"

```
ChannelMapper mapper = ChannelMapper.findByMac(macAddr);
if (mapper != null) {
    String chid = mapper.getChid();
    ChannelId channelId = mapChannels.get(chid);
    Channel channel = channels.find(channelId);
}
```

I'd like to ask if there's a better way to store and retrieve the actual "*Channel*" object? And would it be better if I change `Map<String, ChannelId>` to `Map<String, Channel>` to store "*Channel*" directly?

Comment: After consulting with my colleagues, I've modified to use Map<String, Channel> whose key is "macAddr" and the value is "Channel" object. Without storing record in DB and no ChannelId is kept.